# My spring boot application either redirected to spring security login page or it shows white label error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have created User&Role Entity Classes for creating Simple Registration page by using bootstrap but every time when i go to browser it will redirected to spring security login page I have tried so many ways to prevent this but nothing works for me. so, please give me a solution for this.

1.registration.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Create navigation bar (header) -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" >
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Registration and Login Module</a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </nav>
  
<br>
<br>
 
    <!-- Create HTML registration form -->
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            
                <!-- success message -->
                <div th:if="${param.success}">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">You've successfully registered to our awesome app!</div>
                </div>
            
                <h1>Registration</h1>
            
                <form th:action="@{/registration" method="post" th:object = "${user}">
                    
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label class = "control-label" for="firstName">  First Name </label>
                        <input id = "firstName" class = "form-control" th:field="*{firstName}" 
                               required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label class = "control-label" for="lastName">  Last Name   </label>
                        <input id = "lastName" class = "form-control" th:field="*{lastName}" 
                               required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label class = "control-label" for="email">  Email  </label>
                        <input id = "email" class = "form-control" th:field="*{email}" 
                               required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label class = "control-label" for="password">  Password    </label>
                        <input id = "password" class = "form-control" th:field="*{password}" 
                               required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
                        <span>Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}"> Login here </a> </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

2. application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false&serverTime=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1441
server.port=8084

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
   
#spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration

spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

debug=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

3.POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.javaguides</groupId>
    <artifactId>registration-login-spring-boot-security-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>registration-login-spring-boot-security-thymeleaf</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Thymeleaf and Hibernate</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

4.User Entity Class

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.model;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))//for email should be unique
public class User 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_Name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_Name")
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
    
    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

5.Role Entity Class

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    
    public Role(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

6.UserRepository interface

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> 
{

}
```

7.UserService interface

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.Service;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.User;
import net.javaguides.springboot.web.dto.UserRegistrationDto;

public interface UserService 
{
    User save(UserRegistrationDto registrationDto);
}
```

8.UserServiceImpl.Class

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.Service;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import net.javaguides.springboot.Repository.UserRepository;
import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Role;
import net.javaguides.springboot.model.User;
import net.javaguides.springboot.web.dto.UserRegistrationDto;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        super();
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public User save(UserRegistrationDto registrationDto) 
    {
        User user = new User(registrationDto.getFirstName(), registrationDto.getLastName(), 
                    registrationDto.getEmail(),registrationDto.getPassword(),Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER")));
        
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

9.UserRegistrationDto.Class

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.web.dto;

public class UserRegistrationDto 
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    public UserRegistrationDto() 
    {
        super();
    }

    public UserRegistrationDto(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
}
```

10.UserRegistrationController

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.webb;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


import net.javaguides.springboot.Service.UserService;
import net.javaguides.springboot.web.dto.UserRegistrationDto;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class UserRegistrationController 
{
    private UserService userService;

    public UserRegistrationController(UserService userService) {
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    
    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto()
    {
        return new UserRegistrationDto();
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    public String showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return "registration";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") UserRegistrationDto registrationDto)
    {
        userService.save(registrationDto);
        return "redirect:/registration?success";
    }
}
```

11.Main Class

```
package net.javaguides.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"net.javaguides.springboot.model","net.javaguides.springboot.Repository","net.javaguides.springboot.Service","net.javaguides.springboot.web.dto","net.javaguides.springboot.webb"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"net.javaguides.springboot.model","net.javaguides.springboot.Repository","net.javaguides.springboot.Service","net.javaguides.springboot.web.dto","net.javaguides.springboot.webb"})

@EnableJpaRepositories("net.javaguides.springboot.Repository")
@EntityScan("net.javaguides.springboot.model")
//@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class RegistrationLoginSpringBootSecurityThymeleafApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegistrationLoginSpringBootSecurityThymeleafApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Your entities are wrong, JPA entities require a default no-args constructor to be present. 2. You are trying to hard with all the annotations on your class, ditch all but `@SpringBootApplication` (and remove the `scanBasePackages` attribute. 3. There appears to be no security configuration, so everything is secured and your registration page will be inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot and adding the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency to the classpath, Spring Security will automatically secure all your endpoint by default, thus redirecting you to the `/login` page whenever you try to access a protected resource.

You can either remove the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency if you don't need security at all, or you can permit all endpoints by defining a `SecurityFilterChain` bean, like so:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeRequests((requests) ->
            requests.anyRequest().permitAll();
        );

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

If you need any other kind of customization, the [Spring Security Samples project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples) can be a good entry point.